# Creating folders in google drive from updating rows in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I am able to create folders from an existing list in google sheets. This list keeps growing and I would like for the folders to be created (probably on a time trigger). My problem is that it creates all folders again and that it reruns everything starting from A1... and then there is a problem where it automatically posts the links on B column, and not particularly B1, but sometimes B5, B3...

basically i would like to create folders as the list continues to grow without rerunning everything and place the new hyperlinks in the D column...

I tried using the while function to try to check if the folder has already been created but it doesn't really helped me that much since I end up with an error.

```js
function createAndHyperlink() {
    var ss, sh, parent, parent2, r, v, thisCell, folder
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    sh = ss.getSheetByName('f')
    parent = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
    parent2 = DriveApp.getFolderById("1aKKrybi1uSCJPD6m_L5YXOgAV_DofKCK")
    r = sh.getRange('A1:A')
    v = r.getValues()
    for (var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i++) {
        thisCell = sh.getRange(i + 3, 2)
        if (v[i][0] && !thisCell.getFormula()) {
            folder = parent2.createFolder(v[i][0]);
            thisCell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + folder.getUrl() + '"; "' + v[i][0] + '")');
        }
    }
}
```

There is not an error at the end, but it's not orderly, I mean I'm very close to what I need and would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something Like this:

```
function createAndHyperlink() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('f');
  var parent=DriveApp.getFolderById("1aKKrybi1uSCJPD6m_L5YXOgAV_DofKCK")
  var vr=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);//column 1 is values
  var v=vr.getValues();
  var dr=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow(),1);//column 2 is hyperlinks
  var d=dr.getValues();
  var hr=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1);//column 3 is done ... Prevent old assignment from getting recreated
  var h=hr.getFormulas();
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
    if(v[i][0] && !h[i][0] && !d[i][0]) {
      var folder=parent.createFolder(v[i][0]);
      var formula='=HYPERLINK("' + folder.getUrl() + '"; "' + v[i][0] + '")';
      h[i][0]=formula;
      d[i][0]='Done';
    }
  }
  dr.setValues(d);
  hr.setFormulas(h)
}
```

Comment: Works awesome! Thank you!